# Haskell Stack Persistent error, cannot find -llibpq

Tags: postgresql, haskell, haskell-stack, persistent

I have set up a project, which uses Servant and Persistent, using a PostgreSQL backed. Everything works fine, when I run `stack ghci`, including migration, but when I run `stack build`, I get the following error:

```
Linking .stack-work\dist\29cc6475\build\ServantAuthTraining-exe\ServantAuthTraining-exe.exe ...
C://Users//Chris//AppData//Local//Programs//stack//x86_64-windows//ghc-8.8.3//mingw//bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibpq
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`gcc.exe' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)

--  While building package ServantAuthTraining-0.1.0.0 using:
      C:\sr\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_3.0.1.0_ghc-8.8.3.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\29cc6475 build lib:ServantAuthTraining exe:ServantAuthTraining-exe --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"   
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I am on windows, and very new to all of the mentioned techs.

I can connect to the database via pgAdmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely need to pass something like `--extra-include-dirs=C:\PostgreSQL\8.4\include --extra-lib-dirs=C:\PostgreSQL\8.4\lib` (or whatever path) to `stack` so it knows where to find `libpq`. This can also be configured in your `stack.yaml` as described at https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/latest/yaml_configuration/#extra-include-dirsextra-lib-dirs.

Comment: This worked wonders. my paths were: 
extra-include-dirs: [C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\include]
extra-lib-dirs: [C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\lib]